# How can I include a row after a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of names

1. Bobby
2. Owen
3. Lilly
4. Omar
5. Justin
6. Jamey
7. Oden

I would like to first get only the names that begin with 'o' so I wrote

```
WHERE name LIKE 'O%'
```

Which gave me

1. Owen
2. Omar
3. Oden

I would then like to add names that end with 'y'

1. Owen
2. Omar
3. Oden
4. Bobby
5. Lilly
6. Jamey

But I am having difficulty figuring out how to do so. I am working in oracle btw.

Comment: Formulate your requirements in terms of predicates and you'll get the correct `where` clause: you need names that start with `O` OR end with `y` which results in `where name like 'O%' or name like '%y'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the second condition after an `OR`:

```
WHERE name LIKE 'O%' OR name LIKE '%y'
```

Comment: oh wow that was a really simple answer, I feel silly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE  WHERE name LIKE 'O%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE  WHERE name LIKE '%Y'
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the AND:

```
`WHERE name LIKE 'O%' AND name LIKE '%y'`
```

Comment: That would only get those that both begin with 'O' and end with 'Y'.   It would get 'Only', but not 'Oden' and not 'Billy'.

Comment: Thats true, thanks for pointing that out, you will have to use a combination of AND & OR in order for it to work the way you intend for it to